# How should we use the same version for both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Currently whenever I made changes to React Native applications, I will have to change version number in multiple places

### 1. package.json

```
{
  "name": "My Awesome App",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  ...
}
```

### 2. ios/MyAwesomeApp/Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.2.0</string>
```

### 3. android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.2.0"
```

### 4. Update versioning number in my "About" app component

Is there a much simpler way to handle updating versioning like for example configuring in such a way where Info.plist and build.gradle automatically pointing to package.json?

Comment: you only has to change the number when you build the release apk for uploading on the app store or playstore as app store or playstore is not taking the same version.

Comment: @HusainKhanbahadur: Yes I understand versioning only needed when we uploading to appstore/playstore. What I simply means is when I needed to update, how to make them in-sync? This app is freshly build so the version number expected to be same in both appstore/playstore

Comment: If you want to update the app and just check the on your device without uploading then you don't need to change the version number.

Comment: @HusainKhanbahadur: Somehow I think you don't get my question, anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [react-native-version-up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-version-up) which allows you to bump the version in different ways in your package.json, build.gradle and info.plist.

Personally, I do not go with the approach of keeping all in sync. Since I'm following [semver](https://semver.org/) for all my JS-based projects, it can happen that some changes (i.e. a bugfix) affect only one platform and in that case, I would need to bump the version only for that one platform.

Comment: How do you usually manage your versions? I use semver, but when I push my code to github and release it as I only have one package.json, only one version get bumped-up. I usually then edit the release name like "iOS (1.2.3) / Android (1.2.1)". Do you release different versions (github) and have a package.json in ios and android folder? Thank you in advance